# Как правильно сопоставить на одну таблицу сущность разделенную на несколько классов

Tags: java, nhibernate

Есть таблица на 30 и более полей.
 Я хочу разделить данную таблицу на несколько классов и в каждом классе по 5 полей, чтобы удобней было работать.
Создаю абстрактные классы, которые наследуются друг от друга.
И последний класс будет иметь статус «produce».

```
 @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class OneBaseAbstract {

        @Id
@Column(name = "ID_ISX", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private Long id;

        private String name;

        public OneBaseAbstract() {
        }
    /*
     getters
     setters*/

    / *
     equals and hashCode
     */

     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OneBaseAbstract{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}


public abstract class TwoBaseAbstract extends OneBaseAbstract{

    private Integer num;

    private String mark;

    public TwoBaseAbstract() {
        super();
    }

/*
 getters
 setters*/

/ *
 equals and hashCode
 */


    @Override
    public String toString() {

     String superString = super.toString();
       return superString + "TwoBaseAbstract{" +
        "num=" + num +
        ", mark='" + mark + '\'' +
        '}';

    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "name_table")
public class Produce extends TwoBaseAbstract {

    private String name;

    private String product;

    public Produce() {
        super();
    }

    /*
 getters
 setters*/

/ *
 equals and hashCode
 */
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String superString = super.toString();

        return superString + "Produce{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", product='" + product + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


public interface ProduceRepository 
        extends CrudRepository<Produce,Long> {
}
```

Абстрактных промежуточных классов будет столько, сколько нужно чтобы разделить таблицу.
Например, я использую по 5 полей для каждого класса.

**Производный** класс будет вызываться, чтобы сформировать единую сущность и заполнить поля, которые будут сопоставлены в таблицу.

Правильно ли я применил подход, и нужно ли указать аннотацию **@MappedSuperclass**  на промежуточных абстрактных классов ?

Я ее указал для каждого промежуточного абстрактного класса.

И это работает. 
Тип генерации Id не указывал, так как для этой таблице в oracle стоит триггер, который при вставке новой записи, автоматически формирует id.

Как в этом случае работает вычисление **hash code** и работа **equals** для полностью готового объекта?

Я использую для конвертации **mapstruct**, я должен аналогичную структуру создать на стороне **DTO** ?

Как будет работать **Builder**, если его создать в каждом классе отдельно то же?

**Oбновление**

Использовал плагин InnerBuilder в классе-производителе на стороне DTO автоматически сгенерировал нужные поля.
Для конвертации между DTO и Entity настроен MapStruct по умолчанию (когда объявлен интерфейс Mapstuct, не забывайте выполнить сборку проекта, чтобы потом можно было вызывать конвертер в коде )

Comment: Разделять 30 полей на 6 абстрактных классов, так чтобы получилось наследование высотой 6 - это необдуманный подход. Пусть лучше будет один класс (DTO), но с 30 полями, чем 6 предков с 5 полями в каждом. Почему это плохо? Труднее поддерживать и читать такой код. Вообще не рекомендуется делать предков больше 2, так как это будет запутывать других программистов на проекте. Пожалуйста, оставьте одну DTO с 30 полями :)

Comment: но у нас таблицы на  40, 50, 100 полей и больше и как читать такую entity

Comment: Таблицу на 100 полей явно можно разделить на логические кусочки. Поэтому нужна DTO на 100 полей, она будет нужна для чтения/записи в таблицу и больше ни для каких других задач. Так же нужно будет создать классы POJO, которые бы могли описать эти логические участки из 100 полей, эти классы не будут ни от кого наследоваться, это будут вполне самостоятельные POJO классы. Далее, нужно будет сделать конвертеры, которые будут вычленять логические POJO из главного DTO, и собирать несколько логических POJO в одну большую DTO (если это нужно) для записи, и вот уже с этими POJO можно будет вести работу.

Comment: 1.  а как вы предлагает искать поля в entity и менять в них настройки в аннотациях, а это придется, также придется использовать @PrePersist для установки значений по умолчанию и это не на одном поле. И как это искать.

Comment: 2. Например, вы создали entity на 100 полей и dto на 100 полей, между ними стоит mapsruct(пользуемся только им). Классы Pojo описывающие эти логические участки не должны быть связаны ? Если они не связаны, тогда нужно будет помнить где какой класс, для того чтобы установить значения, которые находятся в разных логических участках.

Comment: 3. нужно будет сделать конвертеры, которые будут вычленять логические POJO из главного DTO, и собирать несколько логических POJO в одну большую DTO (если это нужно) для записи - пример пожайлуста приведите, я для этого и обратился за помощью.

Comment: На данный момент, я добавил аналогичную структуру Dto, настроил MapSruct и это все работает. Я не представляю как сделать цельный dto и как создать pogo классы, которые будут разделять обслуживание этого dto по секциям, а также не представляю как можно создать builder, который бы то же наследовался и затем его можно было вызывать из производного класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно объединить логические группы полей в отдельные классы, но мапить все в одну таблицу с помощью аннотации @Embedded

Довольно неплохо это продемонстрировано [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable)